# Erratic "railway" in Blender

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a pair of rather complex-looking curves, which are both slightly different. Now I'd like to make a cube array fit between the two curves, think of a railway. However, the tutorials online are for a single curve with railway segments (or similar objects). I'm trying to fit a cube array between two curves.

I tried using the vertex groups on the array, as to map each side-face on one of the curves but this gives crazy results. Can anyone help out?

**Single modifier**
This is using one curve modifier. As you can see, there's some ends just "floating".
[image: not working]
Modifier stack:

```
Array - 45, relative offset
Curve - targeting curve 1, with vertex group 1 (looks identical without the vertex group), along X
```

**Two modifiers:**
Now if I add the second modifier, I get all kinds of weird effects (which look fancy but aren't really what I'm trying to achieve; when I change the axis for the 2nd modifier, I just get other, weird looking results):
[image: double modifier]
Modifier stack:

```
Array - 45, relative offset
Curve - targeting curve 1, with vertex group 1, along X
Curve - targeting curve 2, with vertex group 2, along X
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work. Make sure the origins of both curve objects and your cube or at the exact same location, and that their scale is 1, 1, 1 and rotation is 0, 0, 0.

In edit mode, set one face as a Vertex Group.

[image]

Add an Array and 2 Curve modifiers, each one set to a different curve and using either the vertex group or its inverse.

[image]

Alternatively, for a slightly different result, instead of using a Cube, merge everything in edit mode until you have a single vertex at the object origin. Then, with the vertex selected, extrude it and right click to cancel the translation. With the second vertex still selected, add a Vertex Group and assign it.

Add an array modifier and a curve set to one of the railings. Add a Shrinkwrap modifier restricted to the vertex group and set to the opposite railing mesh object that you arrayed earlier.

[image]

Finish with a Skin modifier to get your elongated cube.

[image]

[image]

Note the skin adds a lot of geometry. You can plug a Decimate modifier set to planar at the end to remove unnecessary geometry.